# Can't start MariaDB on debian 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I can't seem to be able to start mariadb sql anymore. Internet says a bunch of things but they all seem to be "risky" and it seems that it really depends on the case. So here is mine. I don't know what/when happened but I am afraid to lose my subscribers data. What do you, superheroes, suggest?
When I try to start mariadb :

```
me@server:# systemctl start mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And with systemctl status mariadb.service:

```
me@server:# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.27 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-12-07 21:04:05 CET; 1min 53s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 13289 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13290 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13292 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environm
  Process: 13339 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13339 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Dec 07 21:03:59 server systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.27 database server...
Dec 07 21:04:01 server mysqld[13339]: 2020-12-07 21:04:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 13339 ...
Dec 07 21:04:05 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 21:04:05 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 07 21:04:05 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.27 database server.
```

And when I go to journalctl -xe, I only get:

```
Dec 07 21:10:04 vps69770 sshd[13784]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=161.35.121.130  user=root
Dec 07 21:10:04  sshd[13712]: Received disconnect from 124.239.216.233 port 59950:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec 07 21:10:04  sshd[13712]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 124.239.216.233 port 59950 [preauth]
Dec 07 21:10:04  sshd[13771]: Failed password for root from 111.201.133.174 port 48444 ssh2
Dec 07 21:10:05  sshd[13771]: Received disconnect from 111.201.133.174 port 48444:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec 07 21:10:05  sshd[13771]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 111.201.133.174 port 48444 [preauth]
Dec 07 21:10:05  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Dec 07 21:10:05 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 07 21:10:05 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.27 database server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1241 and the job result is failed.
Dec 07 21:10:06 server sshd[13784]: Failed password for root from 161.35.121.130 port 37142 ssh2
Dec 07 21:10:06 server sshd[13784]: Received disconnect from 161.35.121.130 port 37142:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec 07 21:10:06 server sshd[13784]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 161.35.121.130 port 37142 [preauth]
```

Which is not a big help
I have no idea what to do. I really don't want to lose my database.
Thanks for your input

Comment: My first suggestion is to ask the question at the right Q/A site. SO is about programming questions. However, this question is not about programming, it is about making sure mysql operates as intended. Dba and serverfault sisters sites of SO offer help with such questions.

Comment: Had the same issue on Debian 10. MariaDB server stopped working, tried restarting it, but it didn't work.
Both `systemctl status mariadb.service` and `journalctl -xe` didn't provide any useful information - there were only general errors there, but when I checked mysql server logs (`tail /var/log/mysql/error.log`) I saw that there's an error: `[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory`

The proper solution in this case would be to check why exactly the server ran out of memory, but in my case simply rebooting it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by deleting/renaming the tc.log `mv -vi /var/lib/mysql/tc.log /root` And restarting the database `service mysql restart`

Comment: It took me literally 2 hours before reaching here and it works like a charm! Thank you very much.

However, I have a question. How this you got the idea of ```tc file``` ?